# Is it possible to access wifi direct API and other windows APIs in PWA for windows 10?

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp, wifi-direct, wpa

I'm planning to create an application for windows that needs access wifi direct api to allow service discovery and advertisement. I come from web and react native background, so after seeing so many options to go with on the microsoft website, i'm not sure what should I go with.

On the microsoft's choose your platform page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/choose-your-platform), they also mentioned PWAs (although close to the bottom). And after checking the PWA page, i'm not sure if it allows access (and to what extent) to the native API, the wifi direct api in particular.

So can someone please tell me if it's possible to access wifi direct api in a PWA and should I really go with PWAs?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access wifi direct API and other windows APIs in PWA for windows 10?

If you plan to build your UWP application through PWA and use some WinRT-API, you need to use Visual Studio 2017.

PWA could access native api with WinRT, but Windows will remove Edge-UWP step by step in the feature, it is may not good recommendation.

For accessing navtive api with WinRT, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript). Please note before access WinRT, you need to add the webset uri then set WinRT access as all in  package.appxmanifest **Content URIs** tab.